# How to shrink log file in SQL Server after unknown period of not being backed up?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I recently took over management of a database that has been in use for 2-3 years, and it had no transaction log maintenance plan in place. The DB file is 8 GB, but the transaction log file is a whopping 54 GB.  I started backing up the log file, and I need to reclaim that drive space.  I have compared my DB to other sites within my company that had proper maintenance plans built, and their transaction logs are roughly 4 GB, which is what I would expect.  This is the first time I've run into this problem.

I performed a full backup of the DB, and set up an initial transaction log maintenance plan, but I need to shrink this *.ldf file, because it is so grossly out of proportion. I searched the Stack Overflow message boards in the hope of finding a similar situation.  Based on that research, I tried the DBCC SHRINKFILE but that did not yield the results I expected. I restored the DB to original (oversized log file in place) and tried the Full-Simple-Full recovery technique to truncate the log, but was still unable to reclaim the space. I even tried deleting the .ldf and going through the process of clearing the (Recovery Pending) status. I went back to the DBCC CHECKDB repair function, but after clearing the (Recovery Pending) status, I was unable to backup the transaction log at all. I started receiving a msg 42000 error 50000, which also referenced error 3013. In the end, I deleted the whole mess and restored it back to it's original state. I;ve tried to be as detailed as possible, and will be happy to clarify or expound if necessary.  As I said, this is the first time I've run into something like this, but I have always started my projects from the beginning.  This is the first time I've jumped into the middle of something that was built by someone else and broken when I got it.

```
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] SET EMERGENCY;

GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBName] set single_user

GO

DBCC CHECKDB ([DBName], REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS;

GO 

ALTER DATABASE [DBName] set multi_user 

GO
```

My expected result is an uncorrupted transaction log that is appropriately sized for my database.  Let this be a cautionary tale and reminder to ask all the questions before accepting management of someone else's screw-up.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but what is your question?

Comment: I might have been too wordy... My question is how do I shrink the transaction log down to an appropriate size without corrupting it?  I know why it is so huge, and I know that it's not supposed to be this way, which  is always the first and second questions I've seen. Also, thanks for fixing my board formatting.  I thought the template would do it automatically.

Comment: [Shrinking a log file to a specified target size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#shrinking-a-log-file-to-a-specified-target-size). If that isn't working as you expect, you should be telling us why.

Comment: If I knew why, I wouldn't be asking you for help, would I?

Comment: If what you see isn't what you expect, but you don't know why, how can it be what you don't expect..? Only you know why it's not what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on 2008 or older you can try 'BACKUP LOG WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY'

Otherwise switch the database to simple recovery, this will clear out the log.
then run DBCC SHRINKFILE to shrink the file size itself.

Comment: DBCC SHRINKFILE not reduce log file ldf. For me log_reuse_wait_desc not returns any data. DBCC SQLPerf(logspace) return 99,99% Log Space Used DBCC LOGINFO returns 11059 rows, all Status = 2.